# My aspx page gets struck half the way during load in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, performance

In my project(classified site) there are many aspx pages. in that i have post page where user can post the ads.. This page is not loading fully.. only half of the page loads and then it stops. This happens only in Internet Explorer(I am using version 8.0)

Browser returns follwing errors:

```
Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
prototype.js
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your JavaScript or maybe JQuery codes?

Try to call that codes when the page is loaded.

Another solution is this:

**Reset your internet explorer settings and run it**. You can do this by following the steps given below.

If the problem is caused by damaged or incompatible Internet Explorer settings or add-ons, you can usually resolve the problem by resetting Internet Explorer settings.

To use the Reset Internet Explorer Settings feature from Control Panel, follow these steps:

1. Exit all programs, including Internet Explorer (if it is running).
2. If you use Windows XP, click Start, and then click Run. Type the following command in the Open box, and then press ENTER:

inetcpl.cpl

If you use Windows Vista, click Start Collapse this imageExpand this image . Type the following command in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER:

inetcpl.cpl

The Internet Options dialog box appears.

1. Click the Advanced tab.
2. Under Reset Internet Explorer settings, click Reset. Then click Reset again.
3. When Internet Explorer finishes resetting the settings, click Close in the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box.
4. Start Internet Explorer again.

Comment: this should be a comment, rather than answer

Comment: Since my page has lots of HTML and JavaScript content. cant find the which script causes this error.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similiar problem and this didnt help but I did find that the client had used the Ctl+Scroll and had Zoomed out to far causing the menu at the top of the page to start stacking.
Hope this helps though this post is older.

JSB